# Scroll eventListener stops working

Tags: javascript

The problem is when I enable the eventListener width the scroll eventListener stops working.

```js
var header = document.getElementById("header");
var nav = document.getElemantById("ulArea");
var HaLogo = document.getElementById("logo");
var yPosition = window.scrollTop();


window.addEventListener("scroll" , yScroll);

function yScroll () {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 100 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 100) {
        header.style.height = "90px";
        logo.style.float = "left";
        logo.style.height = "90px";
        logo.style.width = "90px";
        logo.style.margin = "0px 0px 10px 30px";
        ulArea.style.margin = "0px 0px 0px auto";
        ulArea.style.float = "none";
    } else {
        header.style.height = "220px";
        logo.style.background = "transparent";
        logo.style.float = "none";
        logo.style.height = "150px";
        logo.style.width = "150px";
        logo.style.margin = "0 auto";
        ulArea.style.margin = "0 auto";
        ulArea.style.float = "none";
    }
}

window.addEventListener("width" , headerHeight)

function headerHeight() {
    if (document.getElementById("header").width < 990px) {
        header.style.height = "100px";
    } else {
        header.style.height = "220px";
    }
}
```

Comment: could you set some alerts inside your events so we can see whats happening? your "headerHeight" function should be before eventlistener "width"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code:

1. You need to use the [`resize`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onresize.asp) event (there is no `width` event).
2. I think the `logo` variable isn;t defined, do you mean `HaLogo`?
3. `ulArea` isn't defined.
4. You need to use the [`.style.width`](https://www.w3schools.com/JSREF/prop_style_width.asp) property of the element (`.width` doesn't exist).
5. You need to parse the element's width into an integer with [`parseInt`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp). If you don't parse it you'll be comparing a string like `'50px'` to an int `990`.
6. Change `< 990px` to `< 990` (remove the `px`).

You should end up with `if (parseInt(document.getElementById("header").style.width) < 990) {` for your if statement and `window.addEventListener("resize", headerHeight);` for your second event listener.

Comment: @EbadRaza No problem :) If my answer helped you, can you please [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are actually looking for is the resize event instead of width:

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function(event){
  // do stuff here
});
```